# how can i use kbhit() function while using gcc compiler,as it does not contains conio.h file?

Tags: gcc, c++, c

GCC compiler does not contains  file but i have to use kbhit() function  to make a program, what can i do ? is there any substitution of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux might help.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this as a substitute for for kbhit():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>

char buffer[1];

int main()
{
  fd_set set;
  struct timeval tv;
  struct termios t;

  memset(&tv, 0, sizeof(tv));

  tcgetattr(0, &t);
  t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  /*cfmakeraw(&t);*/
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);

  while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(0, &set);

    select(1, &set, 0, 0, &tv);

    if (FD_ISSET(0, &set)) {
      printf("got input\n");
      read(0, buffer, 1);
    }
    else {
      printf("no input\n");
    }

    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I only ever wanted to detect a keyboard hit as a way to exit some sort of forever loop for tests or whatever. However, I always forget to just hit any key, and tend to use ^C, so typically I also add a ^C handler in these programs so as to exit and cleanup gracefully.

```
void sig_handler(int signo){  /* do not abort on ^C */
   if (signo == SIGINT){
      printf(" --- SIGINT (^C) detected. Terminate gracefully, saving the sample data...\n");
      ctrl_c_flag = 1;
   } /* endif */
} /* endprocedure */
```

And to register:

```
   if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR){ /* register the signal handler */
      printf("\ncan't catch SIGINT\n");
   } /* endif */

   ctrl_c_flag = 0;  /* there has not been a ^C */
```

And then this to exit the forever loop and cleanup:

```
  if (ctrl_c_flag) break; /* exit on ^C */
```

Where `ctrl_c_flag` is a global variable.